# Tie two environments together

Tags: environments

I have a rather large document with the following structure

```
\newenvironment{A}{sth.}{sth.}
\newenvironment{B}{sth.}{sth.}
\newenvironment{C}{sth.}{sth.}
\begin{A}
\begin{B}
\end{B}
\begin{C}
\end{C}
\begin{B}
\end{B}
\begin{C}
\end{C}
\end{A}
\begin{A}
\begin{B}
\end{B}
\begin{C}
\end{C}
\begin{B}
\end{B}
\begin{C}
\end{C}
\end{A}
```

Now I want to prevent the environments `B` and `C` to be separated, either on a column break or a page break. They always are paired such that after environment `B` always an environment `C` follows. One solution is to put both environments into one, i.e. instead of having 
    \begin{B}
    \end{B}
    \begin{C}
    \end{C}
I would have

```
\begin{D}
\end{D}
```

but I would prefer not to do this due to already having quite a lot of text written in that scheme. Another possibility would be to open a `minipage` in environment `B`, and close it in `C`, but that results in `! LaTeX Error: \begin{minipage} on input line 21 ended by \end{C}.`
Is there another solution for that? Or should I rather rewrite the whole document?

Comment: It seems like this shouldn't be too hard with a find-replace: Find `\begin{B}`, replace `\begin{D}`, find `\end{C}`, replace `\end{D}`, find `\end{B}\n\begin{C}`, replace `''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea.

First, the originale definition of A, B and C saved in A, BB and Cc

```
\newenvironment{A}{sth.}{sth.}
\newenvironment{BB}{sth.}{sth.}
\newenvironment{CC}{sth.}{sth.}
```

Then new environment B and C to keep BB and CC in same box.

```
\newsavebox\BC
\newenvironment{B}{%
\global\setbox\BC\vbox\bgroup\begin{BB}}{%
\par\xdef\mtprevdepth{\the\prevdepth}
\end{BB}\egroup}
\newenvironment{C}{%
\setbox\BC\vbox\bgroup\unvbox\BC\prevdepth\mtprevdepth\begin{CC}}{%
\end{CC}\egroup\box\BC}
```

**Update:** here is another idea using `etoolbox` package

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{A}{\textbf{A}sth.}{sth.}
\newenvironment{B}{\textbf{B}sth.}{sth.}
\newenvironment{C}{\textbf{C}sth.}{sth.}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{B}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{C}{\end{minipage}}
```

Comment: Using the `etoolbox`-version was what I am looking for, due to already using other commands in this context (btw., I could have thought about that, too...)